# MYSQL Syntax Error with Two WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, where-clause, mysql-error-1064

I've been working on this piece of code for the last 2 hours and I can't figure out what's wrong it with. I just want to select products added more than a month ago with stock over 20 units. Please, help me.

```
SELECT
    product.prodId,
    product.prodDatAdd,
    product.prodSto,
    product.prodTyp,
    petSupply.petSupId,
    petSupply.petSupNam,
    petSupply.petSupPri
FROM
    product
INNER JOIN petSupply ON product.prodId = petSupply.petSupId
WHERE (product.prodDatAdd < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) )
AND
WHERE (product.prodSto > 20);
```

What is bugging me the most is that I can run the query if I use on of either WHERE but not both.

Comment: Just delete the second `WHERE` word. See also http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the second `WHERE` statement. It is unnecessary and invalid.

```
SELECT
    product.prodId,
    product.prodDatAdd,
    product.prodSto,
    product.prodTyp,
    petSupply.petSupId,
    petSupply.petSupNam,
    petSupply.petSupPri
FROM
    product
INNER JOIN petSupply ON product.prodId = petSupply.petSupId
WHERE (product.prodDatAdd < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) )
AND
(product.prodSto > 20);
```

The parenthesis are unnecessary as well but harmless to have.